# How to improve memcache hitrate?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, memcached

Memcache reports a hit ratio in gae to 32%. I don't know how good that is. Should I try and improve or how do I measure whether this hit ratio is ok? I suppose now that I see that memcache actually does make hits and misses I can try to improve the hit ratio.

```
Statistics Hit count:   2490
Miss count:     5206
Hit ratio:  32%
Item count:     2006 item(s)
Total cache size:   3632355 byte(s)
Oldest item age:    6 hour(s) 4 min(s) 23 second(s)
```

### Update

After careful refactoring I've managed to improve hitrate to 40 %.

Comment: It depends on how your application is preforming, if your application preforms well (performance and budget wise) then your should care about the memache ratio.

Comment: If requests/data access patterns do not re-use cached items much, then cacheing has little effect.  You have quite old items in your cache so stuff isn't expiring rapidly, so I would suggest it's more about the nature of what you are caching that affects you cache hit ratio. I am getting >87% all the time on only 487 items in cache, and the oldest item is only 2 hours old.

Comment: I've managed to improve hitrate to 40 %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your cache size is not even 4MB I would suggest that your cache isn't holding a lot of objects.  Chances are that either your cache is still warming up or you are expiring things too quickly for it to take effect.

You could try increasing the life of items in the cache and see if that helps, although given your overall access numbers I suspect that it's just a case of memcached not being asked to do a lot.